# converting list of dictionaries with a nested dictionary to a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am kind of new to python programming and pandas library.
I have a list looks like below

```
[
 {
  'tradable': False, 
  'mode': 'quote', 
  'instrument_token': 256265, 
  'last_price': 10546.1,
  'ohlc': {
           'high': 10621.7, 
           'low': 10545.3, 
           'open': 10616.7, 
           'close': 10596.4
          }, 
  'change': -0.474689517194512
 }
]
```

I want the nested dictionary with key 'ohlc' to be converted to a dataframe.
In other words, the dataframe columns should be high,low,open,close.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Hello Edwin.. Thank you very much for the solution. I am able to create a dataframe with open high low close values.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [pandas.io.json.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
In [16]: d
Out[16]:
[{'tradable': False,
  'mode': 'quote',
  'instrument_token': 256265,
  'last_price': 10546.1,
  'ohlc': {'high': 10621.7, 'low': 10545.3, 'open': 10616.7, 'close': 10596.4},
  'change': -0.474689517194512}]

In [17]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(d)
Out[17]:
    change  instrument_token  last_price   mode  ohlc.close  ohlc.high  ohlc.low  ohlc.open  tradable
0 -0.47469            256265     10546.1  quote     10596.4    10621.7   10545.3    10616.7     False
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
df=pd.io.json_normalize(d)
columns=['ohlc.open','ohlc.high','ohlc.low','ohlc.low']
df=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=columns)
df.columns=['open','high','low','close']
df
```